# Why does using an unset variable as the array index return element 0 in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

Why is an empty key in a bash array always the zero key element?

Try

```
empty_key=

h[0]=0
h[1]=1
h[2]=2

echo ${h[$empty_key]}
```

Result

```
0
```

Could you please explain, why this behavior is correct?

In my understanding it should not be different to

```
not_existing_key=5 
echo ${h[$not_existing_key]}
```

where the result is just empty.

This is important to understand, if one uses the result for a loop, like in

```
for element in ${h[$key]};do
  ...
done
```

where the empty_key leads to a cycle, but NOT the not_existing_key.

To avoid this behavior it is obviously not to start an array with index 0

OR

replace an empty key by any key value not assigned (what seems to be boring).

Again my question: why is this behavior correct?

EDIT: My question should be understood as why is this behavior the prefered one in the bash world and not an empty result as with a non-existing key value?

Comment: @anubhava: Sorry, your statement is not true. A not_existing_key gives you just an empty result, not the 0-key element

Comment: Please, read again the question text where the not_existing_key has a non-empty value. Fue

Comment: ${h[$not_existing_key]} gives "" whereas $h[] gives 0[]

Comment: Okay, but it does not make your first statement true and this should be clear to the next reader. Thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When accessing an array element, `[]` constitutes an arithmetic context. This has a few consequences:

- no need for `$` to dereference variables:

  ```
  $ arr=(a b c)
  $ idx=1
  $ echo ${arr[idx]}
  b
  ```
- arithmetic operations are evaluated:

  ```
  $ echo ${arr[idx+idx]}
  c
  ```
- variable names are dereferenced in "chains" (*evaluated as an arithmetic expression* in the manual):

  ```
  $ idx=2
  $ idxref=idx
  $ echo ${arr[idxref]}
  c
  ```
- names of null or  unset variables are evaluated to `0` when used without parameter expansion syntax:

  ```
  $ notset=
  $ echo ${arr[notset]}
  a
  ```
- and finally (your question), a null value evaluates to `0`:

  ```
  $ notset=
  $ echo {$arr[$notset]}
  a
  ```

---

Manual quotes:

- [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays):

  > Indexed arrays are referenced using integers (including arithmetic expressions (see [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic))) [...]
- [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic):

  > Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter expansion is performed before the expression is evaluated. Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax. A shell variable that is null or unset evaluates to 0 when referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax. [...] **A null value evaluates to 0.**

Comment: `(your question), names of unset` - hm... not really his question, he does `${h[$not_existing_key]}` not `${h[not_existing_key]}`. Or is it the same? I think this has to do with `echo $[]` printing 0. `required for dereferencing` - but doesn't the variable expansion inside the `[` braces happens before variable expansion of `${` braces? So when `${` expansion happens it only sees empty `[]` braces, because `$not_existing_key` expands to nothing _first_?

Comment: @KamilCuk It's the same because of the first effect, no `$` required for dereferencing.

Comment: *»`variable names are dereferenced in "chains"`«*. It even goes beyond that: Whole *expressions* are evaluated recursively. Example: `a=1; b=a+2; c=b+3; echo $((c))` will print the result of `1+2+3`, that is, `6`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Hmm, it might also be "a null value evaluates to 0". I'll add that.

Comment: @BenjaminW It's exaclty that https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays `Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing with a subscript of 0`. I am only not sure what is the "order of expansions" here - does the `${..[this part]}` expands first or does they expand both at the same time somehow. | I think I understand it more "literally"? It's "arr[subscript]", so without a subscript it would be "arr[]"... :/

Comment: @KamilCuk I think "referencing without subscript" means `$arr`, which is the same as `${arr[0]}`, though.

Comment: @Benjamin W.:I'm sorry that my question was not that clear asked and your answer is therefore corret ( you say: because it is written here). But I'd like to understand why this is the behavior to go with and not that supposed in my question (empty result). Thx.

Comment: @onemorequestion "Why is this the way Bash does it" might only be answered by Chet Ramey.

Comment: @Benjamin W.: True. I proposed one case, where it would be nice to have a different behavior. Could you tell me cases where the actual behavior is necessary/intended?

Comment: @onemorequestion Where do you get your keys from when you run into the potential problem of a key being unset?

Comment: On a result page I use the unset key not to show any child elements as long as no result is requested. Otherwise the key is used to select the used child elements again on the result page. It is esay not to use the 0-element for the key or ask if the key is empty. But I like to know where the actual bash behavoir gives me an advantage or for which cases it was designed.Thx.